# PHP - Get links content from a parsed DOM document

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm writing some code to read HTML document for content, I've been able to ascertain that all the content I care about is encapsulated in a `td` marked with a style:
`<td style="padding:8px 10px;">`

So I use the html dom reader to find me all the `<td>` with match that style, as these are the ones I care about.

The content within this is an anchor, but it has tags within it.

What I'm wanting is to grab the anchor content within the `<td>`, and then grab all the content in the `<b>` and grab all the content in the `<i>`  into seperate variables I can do something with later; perhaps in an array.

I've been able to do a `print_r` of the DOM nodes, but it always returns the textContent without the `<b>` and `<i>`

ie:

```
// Note the tabs are actually from the output 

[textContent] =>                                            Wed 23rd Nov                                                        Red Hot Chilli Pipers
```

My code for this is:

```
// PHP
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$document = "item.html";

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($document);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

task($dom);


function task($dom)
{

  // Get table
  $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

  $results = array();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $div_style = $item->getAttribute('style');
    if ($div_style == "width:100%;border:1px solid #666;") {
      $results[] = $item;
    }
  }

  pre_print_r($results);

}

function pre_print_r($item)
{
  print '<pre>';
  print_r($item);
  print '</pre>';
}
```

The HTML is typically like this;

```
// The tabs are actually part of the content and would need to be stripped out
<td style="padding:8px 10px;">
    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#/b4f0d" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <b style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Wed 23rd Nov</b><br>
        <i style="font-size:18px;">
                                        Some intro text: <br>Some detail text                       </i>
    </a>
</td>
```

The PHP script returns output, I get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DOMElement Object
        (
            [tagName] => table
            [schemaTypeInfo] => 
            [nodeName] => table
            [nodeValue] =>                                              Wed 23rd Nov                                                        Red Hot Chilli Pipers                                                                                                                           
            [nodeType] => 1
            [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
            [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
            [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
            [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
            [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [attributes] => (object value omitted)
            [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
            [namespaceURI] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [localName] => table
            [baseURI] => 
            [textContent] =>                                            Wed 23rd Nov                                                        Red Hot Chilli Pipers                                                                                                                           
        )
// ... array continues here
```

...

[edit]

If I attempt to

```
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$results = array();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $div_style = $item->getAttribute('style');
    if ($div_style == "padding:8px 10px;") {
      foreach ($item->childNodes as $childItem) {
        pre_print_r($childItem->nodeValue);
      }
    }
  }
```

This outputs the contents of the `<td>` but doesn't give me the links, the `<b>` or `<i>` content

as per

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => a
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => a
    [nodeValue] =>                          Wed 23rd Nov                                                        Some artist                                         
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => a
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] =>                        Wed 23rd Nov                                                        Some artist                                         
)
```

...

So, in summary:

I've been able to

1. Grab the `<td style="padding:8px 10px;">`  => [OK]
2. Grab the content within that `td`  => [OK]

**My question:**

But what I'm stuck with is;

1. How to grab the links within the `<td>`
2. How to get all the `<b>` content within the links
3. How to grab all the `<i>` content within the links

Comment: There is childNodes property. I think td element has some children (a tag, for example), where you will find what you need. At a tag you just need to take href attribute to get the link.

Comment: If you're viewing the results of `print_r` in a browser then the HTML tags will be parsed and not displayed, should be visible in the page source though.

Comment: Hi, I tried the childNodes; `foreach ($item->childNodes as $childItem) {
        pre_print_r($childItem->nodeValue);
      }`  this gives me the same content as before; I'm wondering how to do another `getElementsByTagName` within the same content

Comment: By which I mean it returns `[textContent] =>                                            Wed 23rd Nov ...`

Comment: I also use var dump, but its not necessary for me to use it in this example, also the print_r is wrapped in a pre; so it doesn't output the html tags, or at least i hope so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to fix the problem now!

```
// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($document);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

print '<p>Using:' . $document . '</p>';

$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

$events = array();

foreach($tds as $td) {
    $tag_style = $td->getAttribute('style');
    if ($tag_style == "padding:8px 10px;") {
        $links = $td->getElementsByTagName('a');
        $boldTags = $td->getElementsByTagName('b');
        $italicTags = $td->getElementsByTagName('i');

        $eventDate = cleanup($boldTags->item(0)->textContent);
        $eventTitle = cleanup($italicTags->item(0)->textContent);

        $event = array();
        foreach($links as $link) {
            $event['a'] = $link->getAttribute('href');
            $event['date'] = $eventDate;
            $event['title'] = $eventTitle;
        }
        array_push($events, $event);
    }
}

pre_print_r($events);
```

That got it to work!

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => Some hyperlink
            [date] => Tue 12th Jul
            [title] => Some title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => Some hyperlink
            [date] => Thu 28th Jul
            [title] => Some title 2
        )

// array continues ...

)
```

My issue is now resolved.

Thanks!